# How to deallocate memory in go?

Tags: memory-management, go

I have a structure:

```
type xyz struct {
    x int
    y string
}

func f(){
    x := new(xyz) //allocating memory
}
```

But I cannot find any method to deallocate it in go.

- Is it not needed to deallocate it in golang?
- Is there any useful document for how memory allocation/deallocation happens in go?

Comment: I think labeling `new(xyz)` with "allocating memory" is a dangerous assertion: There are **far** more ways in Go which result in an allocation. Even `a:=2` might allocate memory on the heap if `a` escapes. Additionally: Using `new` like that is not idiomatic; using `&xyz{}` is more common.

Answer (score 16):

Go is garbage collected language. You do not have to deallocate memory.

Articles on memory allocation and deallocation in Go.

1. [Garbage collection](http://golang.org/doc/faq#garbage_collection)
2. [Heap and stack allocation](http://golang.org/doc/faq#stack_or_heap)
3. [Discussion on allocation optimization](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/0ec6hawwWQ0)
4. [Variable allocation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/0ec6hawwWQ0)